# Выборка постов в WordPress в период С и ДО

Tags: wordpress

Делаю вот такую выборку постов за 2 недели 7 дней до текущей даты и 7 дней после текущей даты. В итоге получаю посты с 6.02.19 по 20.02.19.

Далее ложу это все в Owl Carousel с выводом по 1 элементу.

Но теперь возник вопрос, как отображать пост с текущей датой или следующей после неё?

Видимым должен быть пост 13.02.19 или позже, но доступны в карусели должны быть с 6.02 по 20.02

**Примеры**

Сегодня - 13.02.19 и есть посты за:

- 06.02.19
- 11.02.19
- 15.02.19 - активный
- 16.02.19

или

- 06.02.19
- 11.02.19
- 13.02.19 - активный
- 15.02.19
- 16.02.19

  ```
  $prevWeek = date( 'Ymd', strtotime( '-7 days' ));
  $nextWeek = date( 'Ymd', strtotime( '+7 days' ));

  $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'schedule',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'order'   => 'ASC',
      'meta_query' => array(
          array(
              'key'       => 'schedule_date',
              'compare'   => '>=',
              'value'     => $prevWeek,
          ),
          array(
              'key'       => 'schedule_date',
              'compare'   => '<=',
              'value'     => $nextWeek,
          )
      ),
      'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
  );
  ```

Получается, если решать это свойствами JS:

- нужно найти дату
- сравнить её с текущей
- подняться вверх к owl-item
- удалить у всех `active`
- и присвоить `active` элементу, дата которого соответствует текущей или ближайшей

  ```
  <div class="owl-item active" style="width: 598px;">
      <div class="schedules__inner scheduleContent">
          <div class="date-changer">
              <span class="date-changer__date">15 Февраля 2019</span>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так я решил этот вопрос

```
$prevWeek = date('Ymd', strtotime('-7 days'));
$nextWeek = date('Ymd', strtotime('+7 days'));

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'calendar',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 18,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'calendar_date',
            'compare' => '>=',
            'value' => $prevWeek,
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'calendar_date',
            'compare' => '<=',
            'value' => $nextWeek,
        )
    ),
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'calendar_cat',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'priority-holidays',
        ),
    ),
);

$the_query = new WP_Query($args);

$posts = get_posts($args);

$today = date('Ymd');
$start = 0;
$currentDate = 0;

$i = -1;

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    if ($currentDate < $post->calendar_date) {
        $i++;
        $currentDate = $post->calendar_date;
    }
    if ($post->calendar_date >= $today && $start == 0) {
        $start = $i;
    }
}
```

И дальше передаю значение в атрибут data-start

```
   <div class="owl-carousel" data-start="<?php echo $start; ?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

В php проходите по массиву с постами, в котором ищите пост с текущей датой или датой близкой к текущей, получаете в переменную его индекс внутри массива. Можно использовать что-то вроде такой конструкции, изменить ее в соответствии с тем, как выглядят ваши выходные данные

```
$posts=[
    "2019-02-12 10:28:57",
    "2019-02-13 10:21:57",
    "2019-02-13 10:25:57",
    "2019-02-13 10:28:57",
    "2019-02-13 10:29:57",
    "2019-02-14 10:28:57",
    "2019-02-15 10:28:57"];
$slider_start=0;
$current_date=time();
$smallest_difference=2147483647;
foreach($posts as $key=>$post){
    $difference=abs(strtotime($post)-$current_date);
    if($difference<$smallest_difference){
        $slider_start=$key;
        $smallest_difference=$difference;
    }
}
```

Затем к div, на который навешивается owlCarousel добавляете data атрибут, в который записываете индекс поста, будет что-то вроде такого

```
<div class="slider owl-carousel" data-start="<?php echo $slider_start; ?>">...</div>
```

Затем там, где инициализируете слайдер

```
$(".slider").owlCarousel({
startPosition: $(".slider").data("start"),
...остальные параметры
});
```

Comment: Да, именно. Текущей дате или ближайшей после неё, если на текущую дату нет постов. Хотелось бы без JS, т.к. я в нём не силен. Использую OwlCarousel

Comment: Дополнил вопрос с примерами

Comment: @eugene_v Изменил комментарий, попробуйте такой подход.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку с data-start, сам код я реализовал немного иначе, чуть позже выложу ответ, вот это атрибут помог